# HTML in Json format fails to get parsed

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am playing around with the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest), and want to parse the json response from the user_timeline GET call. 
You can find an example of such a call [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline).

For this, I am using Jackson, as such :

```
URL url =  new File("D:\\01_perso\\like-minded-friends\\test\\resources\\\\tweet_sample.json").toURI().toURL();
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
//om.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true);
JsonNode node = om.readTree(url);
System.out.print(node.path("id").asLong());
```

The issue is that the parsing fails with the following error :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)
 at [Source: file:/D:/01_perso/like-minded-friends/test/resources/tweet_sample.json; line: 98, column: 26]
```

The error comes from the fact that the JSON contains some HTML hrefs, and that they contain slashes.

```
"source": "<a href="//sites.google.com/site/yorufukurou/\"" rel="\"nofollow\"">YoruFukurou</a>",
```

I am searching for a way to have jackson ignore those characters.

As you can see above, I tried to use the **ALLOW_COMMENTS** feature, but it doesn't work since the html is then taken as a comment and that ends up eating the final comma away from the json, leading to another error.

Is there any way to tell jackson to simply accept those HTML lines, or at least ignore them? (I do not actually need them, so the source elements could simply be skipped.)

Thanks

Comment: Here is a blog post about escaping from the creator himself. http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/08/entry_476.html

Comment: @Ghokun Thanks but if I understand correctly this can only be used for serialization, however I am deserializing my data. The error stays the same even after creating the special ObjectMapper.